# How do I forward inputs of a html form to Drupal 7 login form?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a form in html as follow:

```
<form class="login active">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
        <label><a href="forgot_password.html" rel="forgot_password" class="forgot linkform">Forgot your password?</a></label>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="remember"><!--<input type="checkbox" />--><span><!--Keep me logged in--></span></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
        <a href="register.html" rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account yet? Register here</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I need to do is to make the user login into Drupal using my html form. Thanks in advance

Comment: The theming basics for Drupal are found here : https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-theming-basics-drupal-7?p=1151

Answer (score 0):

In template.php write:

```
<?php
function mytheme_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      $hooks['user_login'] = array(
      'template' => 'templates/user_login',
      'render element' => 'form',
      // other theme registration code...
    );

    return $hooks;
}

function mytheme_preprocess_user_login(&$variables) {
    $variables['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login form');
    $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($variables['form']);
}
?>
```

Then, you can create `user_login.tpl.php` in directory `templates`.

More informations: [Customizing the login form](https://www.drupal.org/node/19855), [function hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am a bit new to Drupal, would show the registration code in Drupal. I would really appreciate that. My aim is to use inputs from a form outside Drupal so that once the user enter his/her credentials, get redirected to Drupal home page in case of successful login. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `hook_menu` to register a custom path for a custom module that will handle your post request can solve your problem : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

After, just use a function like `user_authenticate` to authenticate the user : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_authenticate/7

Both links give you examples.